# there is no scott schema in my oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sqlplus

recently download oracle 11g, tried login using scott, turns out scott doesnt exist . I logged in using sys as sysdba and ran 'show pdbs' but it showed 'unknown show option pdbs'.

I looked up online and found that i need to run the scott.sql. But then i couldnt find the scott.sql file in the expected location. pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

11g is rather old, there's no PDB there.

As you're logged as `SYS`, run the following command and say what status you got (in my database, it is OPEN):

```
SQL> select account_status from dba_users where username = 'SCOTT';

ACCOUNT_STATUS
--------------------------------
OPEN

SQL>
```

If it is LOCKED (which might be), then run

```
SQL> alter user scott account unlock;

User altered.

SQL> alter user scott identified by tiger;

User altered.

SQL>
```

and - finally - connect:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL>
```

---

If you really don't have that schema, create it. See [this](https://o7planning.org/11507/create-oracle-scott-schema) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot , i had to create that schema:)